# Why XeTeX ignore the colors of \xymatrix?

Tags: xetex, color, lyx, xymatrix

I use XeTex because I can put there Hebrew at the math mode.
Here what I put at *xymatrix*:

```
\[
\xymatrix{*+[F*:red]++[F*:blue]++[o][F][green]{abcde}\ar[r] & *{a}}
\]
```

Here is the result with XeTeX: [image]

With pdflatex:
[image]

After I use XeTex when I back to pdflatex it gave the first result....

Do you know why?
Do you know how can I fix it?

Here is the full file:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Anka CLM}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{*+[F*:red]++[F*:blue]++[o][F][green]{abcde}\ar[r] & *{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

And here is my fonts screen:
[image]

Comment: i can't process this because i don't have the fonts.  but i find it strange that one image has a circle, and the other an ellipse.

Comment: Even more strange: some of the packages you are using, such as fontspec, seem not to work with pdflatex. Did you really compile the file with pdflatex? And with xelatex I get all sorts of warnings of the type `Xy-pic Warning: illegal [<shape>] ignored: shape [blue] not defined`. And your code is far from minimal, why are you loading all these things, isn't that a question on xy only?

Comment: Xy-pic does not have a driver for XeTeX.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - but you can replace the fonts with some other fonts you have and compile it, no?

Comment: @marmot - this is what lyx upload, and yes, I compile this file with both....

Comment: @egreg, can you explain more please? xy-pic works fine for me at XeTex, only the colors doesn't work....

Comment: @heblyx Xy-pic does not support color with XeTeX.

Comment: @egreg but there is a way to pass it?

Comment: @heblyx Not that I know.

Comment: @egreg - Thank you! and if you can thing about something - please tell me!!